# Codeigniter Query Builder - finding the number of records from a certain date not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Within codeigntier, I have the following:

```
echo $this->db->where('FROM_UNIXTIME(`last_login`) >=','NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->from('users')->count_all_results();
```

The above produces the result: 0

I used  print_r($this->db->last_query());  to get the actual sql string being run and it is as follows:

```
 SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `numrows` 
 FROM  `users` 
 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(  `last_login` ) >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 
 DAY
```

When I run it from with mysql, I get the correct result: 1.

I am guessing that the escaping is now working or something but cannot figure it out.  Any idea?

====
New update.

Sorry, CI3 spits this out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`last_login`) >= 'NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'
```

Above produces 0 when I run it in mysql.  When I use below, it works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `users`
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`last_login`) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

So it is the the two little apostrophes.  How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi, aside from using `count_all_results()` have you tried using `num_rows();` from CI query builder? Also try adding `$this->db->select('*')` on your query.

Comment: The problem is in the WHERE portion of the sql statement.  The WHERE portion still doesn't change and that appears to be the problem.

Comment: @spreaderman . . . Are you sure the two queries are being run on the same database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, definitely.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Sorry, I just updated the main issue.  Seems apostrophes are the issue

Answer (score 0):

I changed the statement to the following and it worked:

```
$this->db->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(`last_login`) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")->from('users')->count_all_results();
```